# Mismatch on Marketing Cloud query results vs Salesforce report

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, data-synchronization

We have Salesforce data coming into Marketing Cloud (exacttarget) via Data Stream and have a query using the Synchronized data to create a Shared Data Extension.  However, one of my queries isn't giving the correct number of records (223,256) compared to a report in SF (317,673).

My Query looks like this:

```
SELECT
o.id as [Opportunity ID],
...(fields)...

CASE WHEN adloc.Name != '' THEN adloc.Name
ELSE loc.Name END as [Opportunity Location],
...(more CASE statements)...

FROM Opportunity_Salesforce o

LEFT JOIN Location__c_Salesforce adloc
on o.admitted_location__c = adloc.id

...(more LEFT JOIN statements)...

WHERE o.closedate > GETDATE() AND o.isclosed = 'FALSE'
```

I have a nervous feeling that the multiple LEFT JOINs might be my problem (eg it only gives results where all are there?), I'm not a SQL master by any means.

The Salesforce report has the following Filters:

```
Opportunity Close Date greater than TODAY 
AND Closed equals False
```

Answer (score 0):

The left join should be fine.. it'll return null if no match is found.

The issue *may* be with the time portions of the dates.  You can cast SFMC dates as `date` to strip the time portion from the timestamp. This will effectively compare dates to dates, not timestamps to timestamps.  Like this:

```
SELECT
o.id as [Opportunity ID],
...(fields)...

CASE WHEN adloc.Name != '' THEN adloc.Name
ELSE loc.Name END as [Opportunity Location],
...(more CASE statements)...

FROM Opportunity_Salesforce o

LEFT JOIN Location__c_Salesforce adloc
on o.admitted_location__c = adloc.id

...(more LEFT JOIN statements)...

WHERE cast(o.closedate as  date) > cast(GETDATE() as date) 
AND o.isclosed = 'FALSE'
```